# Binding controls and events to JS file in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

this is kind of a new bee question.

So in rails lets say that we have a model called student. For this create the controller and view files and also create a JS file called student.js and include that in application.js.

If i want to bind JS events on lets say students index page then what I am doing currently is that at the bottom of my index.html.erb file I am putting a script tag that says

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    students();
}
```

and then in student.js file I write a function called student() where I bind all the events on the index page.

I was wondering if this is the right way to do it. Since the student.js file is included in application.js and available - should I not be able to call events directly without even putting them inside the student() function and calling student() function from the index page. So an example of this would be -

lets say that I want my student name to be required filed. So on blur of this control I want to display an alert asking the user to fill it up. Just as an example - i know its a bad example - ha ha.

Currently I am doing it as

/// Student.js file

```
function student(){ 
    var name_control = $("#student_name")

    name_control.blur(function() {
    if (name_control.val() === ''){
        alert("name cannot be blank");
    }
 })
}
```

However in the student.js file should i not be able to do this directly -

// Student.js file

```
var name_control = $("#student_name")

name_control.blur(function() {
    if (name_control.val() === ''){
      alert("name cannot be left blank")
    } 
})
```

With that my question is - why do we need to call the student() function from the document.ready() from rails pages. Am I approaching it the wrong way and is there a better way to do this. Or do we have to call the student() function the way I am currently doing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should put the document ready code in the student.js file. So, instead of having a function called student() in that file you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var name_control = $("#student_name")

name_control.blur(function() {
if (name_control.val() === ''){
         alert("name cannot be left blank")
     } 
  })
}
```

That means no script tags containing code in your index.html.erb file

Comment: Thank you so much my dear sir. You helped me here.